# Validar três campos

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Tenho três campos e tenho que validar mandando a mensagem `ng-mensage` do primeiro campo sempre que um valor é trocado e impedindo que o form seja submetido.

A soma do campo `número 2` e `número 3` não pode ser maior que o valor do campo `número 1`.

Como faço essa validação?

```
<form name="form">
    <md-input-container >
      <label>Numero1</label>
      <input required="" 
           name="numero1" 
           ng-model="obj.numero1"      
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/">
      <div ng-messages="form.numero1.$error">
         <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
     <md-input-container>        
      <label>Número 2</label>          
      <input required="" 
           name="numero2" 
           ng-model="obj.numero2"     
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/">        
      <div ng-messages="form.numero2.$error" >
         <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
      </div>        
    </md-input-container>
     <md-input-container >     
      <label>Número 3</label>      
      <input required="" 
           name="numero3" 
           ng-model="obj.numero3"     
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/"> 
      <div ng-messages="form.numero3.$error" >
         <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
      </div>   
    </md-input-container>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção que pode te ajudar é colocar no formulário `novalidate`:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
```

No `controller`, na função de `submit` você consegue captar se o formulário esta válido ou não.

```
$scope.form.$setSubmitted(true);
if (!$scope.form.$valid) return;
```

`$valid` é true ou false se o formulário é válido em si.

Comment: Fabio Luis Alexandre obrigado pela resposta. Eu tenho que validar assim q passar para outro campo e exibir no ng-message

Comment: Ideal então é criar uma diretiva para fazer isso para você, onde é passado o nome do campo a ser verificado e um objeto com os erros a ser exibidos.
você consegue controlar pelo ng-if="ngModelController.$$parentForm.$submitted || ngModelController.$touched"

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages

Esse link é bem legal pra você estudar e aplicar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode submeter se `form != $invalid`, exemplo

```
<form name="form">
    <md-input-container >
      <label>Numero1</label>
      <input required="" 
           name="numero1" 
           ng-model="obj.numero1"      
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/">
      <div ng-messages="form.numero1.$error">
         <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
     <md-input-container>        
      <label>Número 2</label>          
      <input required="" 
           name="numero2" 
           ng-model="obj.numero2"     
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/">        
      <div ng-messages="form.numero2.$error" >
         <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
      </div>        
    </md-input-container>
     <md-input-container >     
      <label>Número 3</label>      
      <input required="" 
           name="numero3" 
           ng-model="obj.numero3"     
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/"> 
      <div ng-messages="form.numero3.$error" >
         <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
      </div>   
    </md-input-container> 
</form>

<md-button flex class="md-raised" ng-click="add(obj)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Confirmar</md-button>
```

Repare que adicionei um botão para submissão

O controller vai ficar dessa forma

```
$scope.result = [];
$scope.add = function (el) {
    if(!$scope.form.$invalid){
    var soma = (parseInt(el.numero3) + parseInt(el.numero2)); 
    if(parseInt(el.numero1) > soma ){
        $scope.result.push(angular.copy(el));
      delete $scope.el;
      $scope.form.$setPristine();
      console.log($scope.result);
      alert('valido!');
    }else{
        alert('invalido!');
    }            
   }
    };
```

Comment: Felipe Duarte o brigado pela resposta. O problema é que eu nao posso validar no botao este é o problema

Comment: vou editar a resposta

Comment: pronto, adicionei a resolução com base no seu código, é provável que funcione

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples seria utilizar o `min`. Nesse caso, coloquei para que o `min` do primeiro input seja igual a soma dos outros dois inputs, e incluí um `ng-message` para o min:

```
<md-input-container >
  <label>Numero1</label>
  <input required="" 
       name="numero1" 
       type="number"
       ng-model="obj.numero1" 
       min="{{ obj.numero2 + obj.numero3 }}"
       ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,10}$/">
  <div ng-messages="form.numero1.$error">
     <div ng-message="required">Este campo é obrigatório.</div>
     <div ng-message="pattern">Apenas números</div>
     <div ng-message="min">Mínimo {{ obj.numero2 + obj.numero3 }}</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

> É necessário colocar `type="number"` nos 3 inputs.

No primeiro input, para que o `min` funcione, é necessário colocar esse `type="number"`. Nos outros inputs também é necessário colocar, do contrário se você digitar 1 e 2 neles respectivamente, o resultado de `{{ obj.numero2 + obj.numero3 }}` vai ser "12" ao invés de "3".

Segue [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nfXITB5DEUY7GFVA6AwH?p=preview) para testes e análises.